# Read embedded entity from python ndb client

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I am using the google cloud datastore python client to write an entity into the datastore which contains an embedded entity. An example entity might look like:

```
data_type: 1
raw_bytes: <unindexed blob>
values: <indexed embedded entity>
```

I checked the data from the console and the data is getting saved correctly and the values are present.

Next, I need to run a query from a python app engine application. I have represented the above as the following entity in my app engine code:

```
class DataValues(ndb.Model):
    param1 = ndb.BooleanProperty()
    param2 = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    param3 = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class MyEntity(ndb.Expando):
    data_type = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    raw_bytes = ndb.BlobProperty()
    values = ndb.StructuredProperty(DataValues)
```

One of the filters in the query depends on a property in `values`. Sample query code is as below:

```
MyEntity.query().filter(MyEntity.data_type == 1).filter(MyEntity.values.param1 == True).get()
```

I have created the corresponding composite index in my index.yaml 
The query runs successfully but the resulting entity contains the embedded entity `values` as None. All other property values are present.

What can be the issue here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add properties of `DataValues` entity as properties of the `MyEntity`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, but since datastore attributes are kind of keyed by both their name (in this case `values`) *and* the name of the "field type/class" (i.e. `StructuredProperty`), this might fix your problem:

```
class EmbeddedProperty(ndb.StructuredProperty):
    pass

class MyEntity(ndb.Expando):
    data_type = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    raw_bytes = ndb.BlobProperty()
    values = EmbeddedProperty(DataValues)
```

Give it a shot and let me know if `values` starts coming back non-null.

Comment: Let me give this a try. Will let you know. Thanks !

Comment: @sshntt can you confirm whether this solution solved your issue or not.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding back but as of now, I have not got around to implement the above solution. In the above case, for now, I removed the DataValues entity and added its properties as properties of the MyEntity. I will try to implement the above solution in another project and respond back here. If anyone gives it a go before me, please let me know here, so that I can accept the solution. Sorry for the delay again.

Comment: @sshntt could you write your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem, wanting to convert the embedded entity into a Python dictionary. One possible solution, although not a very elegant one, is to use a GenericProperty:

```
class MyEntity(ndb.Model):
    data_type = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    raw_bytes = ndb.BlobProperty()
    values = ndb.GenericProperty()
```

`values` will then be read as an "Expando" object: `Expando(param1=False,...)`. You can access the individual values with `values.param1`, `values.param2` etc. I would prefer having a custom model class, but this should do the job.